# List<? extends A> access to extended classes methods

Tags: java, list, generics

I have 4 classes (B, C, D, E) that extends one class (A), i'm trying to create a generic
`List<? extends A>` to add objects of one of the classes (B, C, D, E). I can do it without problem. The problem is just that i can't access the methods of the classes (B, C, D, E). Is there another way to do this?

Part codes

```
public class A{
    protected int id;

    public void setId(int id){}
    public int getId(){}
}

public class B extends A{
    private name;

    public void setName(String name){}
    public void getName(){}
}

public class Generic{
    List<? extends A> myList;

    public List<? extends A> getMyList(){}
    public void setList(ArrayList<? extends A> MyList){}
}
```

And this is what I do.

```
Generic myObject = new myList<B>;
myObject.getMyList().get(counter).getId();
```

The code above works fine, what I want to do but i can't it's below.

```
myObject.getMyList().get(counter).getName();
```

Comment: Where are you trying to access the methods from?

Comment: Can't you use polimorphism? I mean, use abstract method in `A` and `@Override` them  in the subclasses? If you keep objects in a collection, then you _should_ treat them uniformly. Of course there are special cases when you actually need what you are trying to achieve, but _no special case is special enough_. Think better about your design :)

Comment: I don't believe you that you can add objects to a list of type `List<? extends A>` without any problem. Please show us your code. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Thee are multiple possibilities:

1. Move the method definitions to the base class (as abstract methods)
2. Check with instance of for the concrete class and cast accordingly
3. Define the methods in interfaces (one for method x, one for method Y, etc.) and use the "&" notation: `List<? extends A & Y & Z >` (Y and Z are interfaces here)

Answer (score 0):

Someone posted the code above and then deleted it.

```
public class Generic<T extends A> {
    List<T> myList;

    public List<T> getMyList(){}
    public void setList(ArrayList<T> MyList){}
}
```

That solved my problem, thanks!